# Python split video file into smaller parts

Tags: python, django, video, split, view

I am stuck with my project(web application using Python-Django) on converting a large file(say 1GB) to small parts using python.I could create the large file into smaller parts,but the problem is only the part 1 gets played and rest of the files wont open.

I understood i need to specify the video information before the video data but i dont know how.
Below is my code and someone help me how i could split the the large file into smaller ones.

[N:B] I need to split the video from the django views when the upload is completed

```
def video_segments(video):

    loc = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + format(video.video_file)
    filetype = format(video.video_file).split(".")
    data = None
    i = 0
    start_index = 0
    end_index = 1024000
    file = Path(loc)
    size = file.stat().st_size
    file = open(loc, "rb")
    while end_index < size:
        i=i+1
        file.seek(start_index)
        bytes = file.read(end_index-start_index)
        newfile = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"/"+filetype[0]+format(i)+"."+filetype[1],"wb")
        newfile.write(bytes)
        start_index = end_index + 1
        end_index = end_index + 1024000
`
```

Comment: So you already did it but you want to know how to do it?

Comment: @Goyo The OP is stating that 'I understood i need to specify the video information before the video data but i dont know how. ` and 'rest of the files won't open'. They clearly haven't solved their question.

Comment: @AdiC Sure, otherwise they wouldn't be asking. What I am trying to state is that the question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are serving something like H.264 with a MP4 header to a modern www-browser.

If you chop video-files into parts like this the second part won't have any header and therefore will not play in any browser.

The question is why you are doing this at all.
Normally the entire file is served to the browser and the browser gets the parts it needs with HTTP partial file retrieval, modern browsers are smart enough to get only the parts they need assuming the video file in encoded correctly for this purpose.

Comment: I need partial request of files to seek the video which django doesn't support and i am on a tight schedule.So i thought splitting up the files into smaller pieces and loading the necessary part would solve my problem temporarily @Jimmy Engelbrecht